# Como descobrir se um número é ímpar ou par?

Tags: vba, matemática, operadores

Como achar pares e ímpares desta lista?

```
Sub kati()
For li = 1 To 10
For col = 1 To 10
```

Comment: E cadê a lista?

Comment: Alguma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não sabe como fazê-lo. Assim ajuda a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 8):

Use o [operador Mod](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Se o resto da divisão por 2 é 0, então o número é par. Exemplo:

```
If li Mod 2 = 0 then 'faça o que quiser aqui
If col Mod 2 = 0 then 'faça o que quiser aqui
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Mod.vba).

Answer (score 2):

Idem ao operador **Mod**, pode ser feito assim (considerando que se trata de uma matriz):

```
If Matriz(li, col) / 2 - Int(Matriz(li, col) / 2) = 0 Then MsgBox Matriz(li, col) & " é Par" Else MsgBox Matriz(li, col) & " é Impar"
```

Comment: Muito bom Leo, gostei muito, só fiquei com uma duvida, poderia explicar a operação matematica?

Comment: Claro, ao dividir um número inteiro por 2, se não houver resto ele é par, se houver resto ele é impar. A equação pega o resultado da divisão por 2 e subtrai da parte inteira deste mesmo resultado, se der 0 é que não houve resto, então o número é par; se der 0,5 é que teve resto, então o número é impar. Por exemplo: 18/2 - INT(18/2) = 9 - 9 = 0 (Par), 23/2 - INT(23/2) = 11,5 - 11 = 0,5 (Ímpar), é isso.